# Gnuroot Wheezy fails to install on Android 7.0

Tags: debian, android, gnuroot

I've just installed Gnuroot and Gnuroot Wheezy on my Samsung phone (Android 7.0). I can't get past the *Creat New Rootfs* stage, though: my device says "unpacking a rootfs", thinks for a few seconds then stops.

Any thoughts?

Comment: And am I even in the right flavour of stackexchange?

Comment: Your question is on-topic, but this is the second question we've had ever that mentions gnuroot, so there may be no one around who's used it.

Comment: I'm facing this issue too. After I've updated my android I cannot use gnuroot anymore. 

It is actually being installed, but there's no shortcut created, and theres no option "open" in google play app, only "uninstall" is present. But app is installed for sure. I can see it in app manager. 

There is a potential replacement for it, which is Debiannoroot. But I was unable to install any apps there, even though system seems to be running without any problems (actually it seems way more slow comparing to gnuroot).

Comment: @lebelinoz On topic but consider android.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

I've found a workaround which allowed me to install aboriginal and fedora flavors.

1. Remove all GnuRoot apps. Even though they're not displayed in menu,
   you can still see them in app manager.
2. Install GnuRoot (not GnuRoot Debian, Fedora or any other flavor, just a GnuRoot which is apparently a kind of rootfs manager)
3. Launch an app.
4. Select "create new rootfs" option, and choose a flavor (wheezy does not work, aboriginal and fedora launched on my system)
5. Press Create New Rootfs (this will take you to googleplay), and install image info.
6. Launch GnuRoot (manager) again, choose the same flavor and click "Create New Rootfs". GnuRoot should start unpacking rootfs.

After all these steps done, you should be able to select installed rootfs and launch it.

UPDATE: wheesyx works also

UPDATE: although I was able to launch pretty much all available images excluding wheesy, I couldn't install anything due to permission issues. So currently, I believe, the only way to run linux on android 7 without rooting it is Limbo Pc Emulator. It also have one more advantage: it's alive. Last update currently is on July 2017.

UPDATE: actually, I've found out that new GNU Root Debian was released in may 2017 which runs with no problems on latests android, but search shows old versions first, so you'll have to check update date before installing.